# Writing arraylist to csv file in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is the code I have and essentially I want to write this into a `csv` file:

```
ArrayList <String> course = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <String> name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Integer> age = new ArrayList<>();

File file = new File("jj.csv");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write("Course,Name,Age");
bw.newLine();
for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
    bw.write(course.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}


for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
    bw.write("," + name.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < age.size(); i++) {
    bw.write("," + age.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}

bw.close();
fw.close();
```

I want the output to be in this format, I'm getting an output where the second and third-row are all over the place :

```
Course   Name    Age
math     john    7
english  bob     9
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "all over the place"? If you mean the output you included, that's not comma-separated.

Comment: Are you writing to a csv file or to the console, or both?

Answer (score 1):

I think use `MessageFormat.format()` method(it's in java.text package)  is a good solution.This is a example:

```java
@Test
    public void test05(){
        final String formatTemplate = "{0},{1},{2}";
        List<String> course = Arrays.asList("course0","course1");
        List <String> name = Arrays.asList("name0","name1");
        List <Integer> age = Arrays.asList(1,2);
        final int size = course.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final String lineString = MessageFormat.format(formatTemplate, course.get(i), name.get(i), age.get(i));
            System.out.println(lineString);
            //TODO: bw.write(linString);bw.newLine();
        }
    }
```

Can get:

```
course0,name0,1
course1,name1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the insertion of a newline after each write and use one loop, I will assume the three lists have the same size

```
for(int i=0;i<course.size();i++) {
    bw.write(course.get(i));
    bw.write(","+name.get(i));
    bw.write(","+age.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

, or use in one-line

```
for(int i=0;i<course.size();i++) {
    bw.write(course.get(i) + ","+name.get(i) + ","+age.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell from your question, you can do it like this.  It writes to the file and to the console.

Some data

```
List<String> course = List.of("math", "english", "chemistry");
List<String> name = List.of("John", "Mary", "James");
List<Integer> age = List.of(19, 20, 20);

// file destination and format string
File file = new File("jj.csv");
String format = "%-10s %-8s %-4s%n";
```

- This uses try-with-resources to open and close the writer.
- Process the lists in a single loop

  - use `System.format` to format the values for the `csv` file
  - and use `System.printf` to format them to the console.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw =
        new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    bw.write("Course,Name,Age");
    
    System.out.printf(format, "Course", "Name",
            "Age");
    for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
        // for csv file
        String s =  String.format(",%s,%s,%s",course.get(i),
                        name.get(i), age.get(i));
        // for console
        System.out.printf(format, course.get(i),
                name.get(i), age.get(i));
        bw.write(s);
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

prints

```
Course     Name     Age 
math       John     19  
english    Mary     20  
chemistry  James    20
```

You might want to consider creating a class to hold hold the student information.

```
class Student {
       private String name;
       private String course;
       private int age;
    public Student(String name, String course, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s, %s]", name, course, age);
    }
}
```

Then you can put it in an `ArrayList` like this.

```
 
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new Student("John", "math", 19),
                new Student("Mary", "english", 20),
                new Student("John", "James", 20)));
```

And print using a loop.

```
for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

prints

```
[John, math, 19]
[Mary, english, 20]
[John, James, 20]
```

The output format is controlled by the `toString` method of the class and can be adjusted to meet your requirements.